# log4j2 xml configuration with console

Tags: log4j2

I am tring below configuration for rollover and SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy but its not working.

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-5level [%t] %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1" />
    </Console>
    
    
</Appenders>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you think should happen with this configuration? The console appender writes to the standard output stream, which means the messages are being passed to the operating system and they are usually displayed in the terminal window although they might be routed somewhere else. Wherever that would be is controlled by the operating system, not Log4J.

As such, the console appender doesn’t support triggering policies or a rollover strategy because it has no idea what “rolling” means.

Comment: in that case can i delete older comments using some configuration.